# Failed to resolve directive. Почему не устанавливается локальная директива?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend

```
<template lang="pug">
  button.btn
    slot
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    directives: {
      light: { bind () { console.log('test') } }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Использую так

```
<template lang="pug">
  ui-button(v-light) Button
</template>

<script>
  import UiButton from '~components/ui/button.vue'

  export default {
    components: { UiButton }
  }
</script>
```

Глобальные директивы работают нормально почему не устанавливается локальная директива?

Backtrace из консоли

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve directive: light

warn    @   vue.runtime.esm.js:475
resolveAsset    @   vue.runtime.esm.js:1420
normalizeDirectives$1   @   vue.runtime.esm.js:5733
_update @   vue.runtime.esm.js:5660
updateDirectives    @   vue.runtime.esm.js:5652
invokeCreateHooks   @   vue.runtime.esm.js:5230
initComponent   @   vue.runtime.esm.js:5166
hydrate @   vue.runtime.esm.js:5495
hydrate @   vue.runtime.esm.js:5508
hydrate @   vue.runtime.esm.js:5508
hydrate @   vue.runtime.esm.js:5508
hydrate @   vue.runtime.esm.js:5508
hydrate @   vue.runtime.esm.js:5508
hydrate @   vue.runtime.esm.js:5508
hydrate @   vue.runtime.esm.js:5508
hydrate @   vue.runtime.esm.js:5508
hydrate @   vue.runtime.esm.js:5508
patch   @   vue.runtime.esm.js:5582
Vue._update @   vue.runtime.esm.js:2410
updateComponent @   vue.runtime.esm.js:2534
get @   vue.runtime.esm.js:2877
Watcher @   vue.runtime.esm.js:2866
mountComponent  @   vue.runtime.esm.js:2538
webpackJsonp../node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js.Vue$3.$mount    @   vue.runtime.esm.js:7397
init    @   vue.runtime.esm.js:3497
hydrate @   vue.runtime.esm.js:5492
patch   @   vue.runtime.esm.js:5582
Vue._update @   vue.runtime.esm.js:2410
updateComponent @   vue.runtime.esm.js:2534
get @   vue.runtime.esm.js:2877
Watcher @   vue.runtime.esm.js:2866
mountComponent  @   vue.runtime.esm.js:2538
webpackJsonp../node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js.Vue$3.$mount    @   vue.runtime.esm.js:7397
init    @   vue.runtime.esm.js:3497
hydrate @   vue.runtime.esm.js:5492
patch   @   vue.runtime.esm.js:5582
Vue._update @   vue.runtime.esm.js:2410
updateComponent @   vue.runtime.esm.js:2534
get @   vue.runtime.esm.js:2877
Watcher @   vue.runtime.esm.js:2866
mountComponent  @   vue.runtime.esm.js:2538
webpackJsonp../node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js.Vue$3.$mount    @   vue.runtime.esm.js:7397
init    @   vue.runtime.esm.js:3497
hydrate @   vue.runtime.esm.js:5492
hydrate @   vue.runtime.esm.js:5508
patch   @   vue.runtime.esm.js:5582
Vue._update @   vue.runtime.esm.js:2410
updateComponent @   vue.runtime.esm.js:2534
get @   vue.runtime.esm.js:2877
Watcher @   vue.runtime.esm.js:2866
mountComponent  @   vue.runtime.esm.js:2538
webpackJsonp../node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js.Vue$3.$mount    @   vue.runtime.esm.js:7397
init    @   vue.runtime.esm.js:3497
hydrate @   vue.runtime.esm.js:5492
hydrate @   vue.runtime.esm.js:5508
patch   @   vue.runtime.esm.js:5582
Vue._update @   vue.runtime.esm.js:2410
updateComponent @   vue.runtime.esm.js:2534
get @   vue.runtime.esm.js:2877
Watcher @   vue.runtime.esm.js:2866
mountComponent  @   vue.runtime.esm.js:2538
webpackJsonp../node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js.Vue$3.$mount    @   vue.runtime.esm.js:7397
mountApp    @   client.js:525
_callee3$   @   client.js:559
tryCatch    @   runtime.js:65
invoke  @   runtime.js:299
prototype.(anonymous function)  @   runtime.js:117
step    @   asyncToGenerator.js:17
(anonymous) @   asyncToGenerator.js:28
Promise resolved (async)        
step    @   asyncToGenerator.js:27
(anonymous) @   asyncToGenerator.js:28
Promise resolved (async)        
step    @   asyncToGenerator.js:27
(anonymous) @   asyncToGenerator.js:35
F   @   _export.js:35
(anonymous) @   asyncToGenerator.js:14
mountApp    @   client.js:506
Promise resolved (async)        
./.nuxt/client.js   @   client.js:58
__webpack_require__ @   bootstrap e6c92eb…:710
fn  @   bootstrap e6c92eb…:116
0   @   .*\.(js|ts)$:7
__webpack_require__ @   bootstrap e6c92eb…:710
webpackJsonpCallback    @   bootstrap e6c92eb…:25
(anonymous) @   app.c871916….js:1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, что использовать эту директиву можно только в шаблоне компонента, в котором она создана.

Comment: Проверил вашу теорию. Вы правы, в индексном компоненте объявил директиву, заработала. Но как теперь присвоить эту директиву именно в определенный компонент, не хочу захламлять индекс

Comment: Если директива используется в нескольких компонентах я бы объявил глобально и забыл. Но в принципе можно сделать миксин с директивой и подключать его только в нужные компоненты.